# How to perform disable imageButton in android?

Tags: android

I want to do disable ImageButton(means Physically button shown but user can not click over there) in android,I know Invisible but through which ImageButton not show on screen, Can u tell me it is posible in android? How?

Answer (score 1):

> Can u tell me it is posible in android?

Yes, it's possible in android.

like,

```
ImageButton imgButton  = new ImageButton(this);
imgButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `myImageButton.setEnabled(false);` for exemple.

Answer (score 0):

its possible

just add  this in image button in your xml file

```
 android:clickable="false"
```